# What was the name of the parallel implementation of Linq (not from Microsoft)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, concurrency, parallel-processing

I remember seeing a link about it here where some people claimed it's 1000 times faster than the BCL Linq.

Anyone used it here? Is it true?

Also is Microsoft's PLinq gonna be along the same lines? Because it seemed to me like the above mentioned Linq was automatically parallel or something.

And if that's the case, why isn't Microsoft doing the same with the standard Linq?

Comment: Linq is a language extension, but it comes in many flavours. Are you referring to LinqToObject, LinqToSql, LinqToXml etc. ?

Comment: Linq to Objects I guess. I don't remember the 3rd party linq to be specific or general like MS Linq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with parallel anything, but [Indexed LINQ](http://www.codeplex.com/i4o) lets you add indexes to LINQ-to-Object queries, and claims some pretty dramatic speed-ups in certain cases. Could you be thinking of that?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I know is that the SqlDataReader is significantly faster than LINQ to SQL.